# Difference in behavior using parent.window.location.replace vs parent.location.replace in IE8

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

Scenario: To change the URL of the parent window from within a cross-domain iframe.

In **IE-8** `parent.location.replace("http://google.com");` works fine whereas `parent.window.location.replace("http://google.com");` DOESN'T works (throws Permission Denied).

Whats the difference when i do parent.location vs parent.window.location? And why is this different only in IE 8 (as both works fine in FF/Chrome)

Answer (score 3):

This was a huge help for me - in understanding a similar situation... re: window.foo and just foo... i think it's highly relevant as it relates to the window's object versus just an object in javascript-land.

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/checking-for-undefined-null-and-empty-variables-in-javascript

Down near bottom of his post... (hope it helps).